# Execute logic before each command line .bashrc

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to add some logic to be executed each time I just press enter in the unix terminal, eg print hello:

```
sergei_rudenkov@ws18851:~$ 
Hello
sergei_rudenkov@ws18851:~$
```

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I found the way to print sting each time I launch new terminal, but I didn't find place to execute some logic each time the new `command line` appears.

Could you help me and is it possible at all?

Comment: Do you want to execute the code "each time you press enter" (eg, before running a command) or "each time the new [prompt] appears" (eg, after running a command)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of `PROMPT_COMMAND` are executed just before each prompt is displayed.

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo hello'
hello
$
hello
$ echo foo
foo
hello
$
```